# Linq - choosing item or a default from a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items, for localisation of strings, stored in a SQLite database. I want to retrieve the list, and create a dictionary of items for display purposes using linq. If a localised string does not exist, then I want to return the default language string.

example data

```
Item    MetaTag     LanguageCode    Text
1       Hello       en              Hello
1       Hello       fr              Bonjour
1       Hello       de              Guten Tag
1       Goodbye     en              Goodbye
```

so if I want German strings, the dictionary should contain

```
1       Hello       de              Guten Tag
1       Goodbye     en              Goodbye
```

So I have the following code:

```
public interface ILocalisedItem
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int ItemId { get; set; }
    string MetaTag { get; set; }
    string LanguageCode { get; set; }
}
public class ItemString : ILocalisedItem
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    int ItemId { get; set; }
    string MetaTag { get; set; }
    string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    string Text {get; set; }
}

public static IDictionary<string, T> GetMetaDataDictionary<T>
    (int ItemId, string DisplayLanguage, string DefaultLanguage)
    where T : ILocalisedItem, new()
{

    IEnumerable<T> metadata = GetMetaData<T>(ItemId);

    ILookup<string, T> _lookup = metadata
        .Where(z => (z.LanguageCode == DisplayLanguage) || (z.LanguageCode == DefaultLanguage))
        .OrderBy(x => (x.LanguageCode == DisplayLanguage) ? 0 : 1)
        .ToLookup(o => o.MetaTag);

    return _lookup.ToDictionary(y => y.Key.ToLower(), y => y.First());
}
```

This code seems to work, but I think there must be a better way to do this. Can anyone help provide a better solution.

Comment: Why not send filtered data from database? And then, just use whatever database returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consolidate the statement to something along the lines of:

```
ILookup<string, T> _lookup = metadata
    .Where(z => (z.LanguageCode == DisplayLanguage) || (z.LanguageCode == DefaultLanguage))
    .OrderBy(x => (x.LanguageCode == DisplayLanguage) ? 0 : 1)
    .GroupBy(x => x.MetaTag)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.ToLower(), y => y.First());
```

It isn't a ton cleaner but avoids the extra lookup conversion. I think your approach of pulling both and filtering is going to be the most efficient way of pulling the data. Going directly to the dictionary *should* push the first operation back to the database but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is a little better, makes me happy my approach is not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a custom argument:

```
ILookup<string, T> _lookup = metadata
        .Where(z => (z.LanguageCode == DisplayLanguage) || (z.LanguageCode == DefaultLanguage))
        .DefaultIfEmpty( defaultLanguage )
        .OrderBy(x => (x.LanguageCode == DisplayLanguage) ? 0 : 1)
        .ToLookup(o => o.MetaTag);
```

You have to provide a variable `defaultLanguage`.